# OpenCV gving error "ASSERT: "false" in file qasciikey.cpp, line 495" on multiple windows

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to use multiple OpenCV windows in python on my Jetson TX2. However, I get the error: "ASSERT: "false" in file qasciikey.cpp, line 495"

Below is the minimum reproducible code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1=np.random.randn(300,400)
img2=np.random.randn(600,400)

cv2.imshow('win1', img1)
cv2.imshow('win2', img2)
```

And here is the error trace:

```
Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface.
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 145 (Unknown), sequence: 164, resource id: 0, major code: 139 (Unknown), minor code: 20
Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface.
ASSERT: "false" in file qasciikey.cpp, line 495
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please help. Thanks!

**EDIT:** 
The error only happens when I ssh into the Jetson (via MobaXterm v10.5). If I run the code directly from the Jetson, I do not get this error.

Answer (score 3):

I found that un-checking "Unix-compatible keyboard" in MobaXterm/Settings/X11, with keyboard set to "us" solved this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message (`ASSERT: "false" in file qasciikey.cpp, line 495`) when running code on Raspberry Pi. I was able to make this problem go away by using `cv2.namedWindow()` first to create a window where images should be displayed.

You should try this solution and see if the problem goes away:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1=np.random.randn(300,400)
img2=np.random.randn(600,400)

cv2.namedWindow('win1')
cv2.namedWindow('win2')

cv2.imshow('win1', img1)
cv2.imshow('win2', img2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is the reason for this, but it happens to me when I run OpenCV with CUDA and *my ubuntu latptop is running on Batteries*

As soon as I connect it to the power cord, this stops happening.